# Ankhsvn integration with Redmine

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2010, ankhsvn, redmine, redmine-plugins

Just out of curiousity I'm deploying AnkhSVN with Visual Studio 2010 in our development office, and have had much success with Redmine in managing projects.  However, one issue is integrating AnkhSVN with Redmine in regard to Issues.  So I can submit a commit against for a particular bug fix.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made a simple plugin
[http://ankhredmineex​te.sourceforge.net/](http://ankhredmineexte.sourceforge.net/).
Read readme for instructions

Comment: Gorgeous!  Thank you very much!  Installed and working.  Your getting an upvote as well! :-)

Comment: Actually I've just posted an issue on sourceforge; https://sourceforge.net/projects/ankhredmineexte/forums/forum/1327321/topic/4015665

Comment: Any plan to extend support to Visual Studio 2017?

Answer (score 2):

This is not related to AnkSVN only to SVN. To relate a issue to a particular issue you can write something like the following in your log message:

```
refs #1234
```

Which references your commit to the issue #1234.

You can also give

```
fixed #1234
```

Which will set the issue to "closed" based on the configuration you made in Redmine.

Comment: Thanks for that, but there's no way to populate the issues window in AnkhSVN ?  Rather than knowing the bug number you have a fix for.

Comment: I didn't talk about a issue windows in AnkSVN but you have to give a log message during the commit.

Comment: Agreed, you answered my initial question. Thanks!  I should of added that I wanted to populate the issues window inside AnkhSVN.  My fault.